# Bring a minimized Window to the front in Python

Tags: python, winapi

I am currently writing on a program that is opening PuTTy Sessions on the click of a button. Now I want the program to recognise wether a Session is already open and to open the minimized window. Unfortunately, I can't install new libraries via pip, as it doesn't work on the companies Laptop (win32gui seems to not be installed).

This is my current code:
(I know it's not beautiful, I just started programming)

```py
import tkinter
import os

def rt010ac(): 
    os.system("start C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\putty.exe -load rt010ac")
def rt020ac(): 
    os.system("start C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\putty.exe -load rt020ac")
def rt020bd(): 
    os.system("start C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\putty.exe -load rt020bd")
def core1(): 
    os.system("start C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\putty.exe -load core1")
def core2(): 
    os.system("start C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\putty.exe -load core2")
def rt030ac(): 
    os.system("start C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\putty.exe -load rt030ac")
def rt030bd(): 
    os.system("start C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\putty.exe -load rt030bd")

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("1920x1080")

bg=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Background.png")
label=tkinter.Label(image=bg)
label.place(x=0,y=0)
photo=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Router.png")

milchButton = tkinter.Button(
    text="rt020ac",
    font=("Arial",14),
    image=photo,
    command=rt020ac,
    highlightthickness=0,
    borderwidth=0,
    compound=tkinter.TOP
    )
milchButton2 = tkinter.Button(
    text="rt020bd",
    font=("Arial",14),
    image=photo,
    command=rt020bd,
    highlightthickness=0,
    borderwidth=0,
    compound=tkinter.TOP
    )
milchButton3 = tkinter.Button(
    text="rt010ac",
    font=("Arial",14),
    image=photo,
    command=rt010ac,
    highlightthickness=0,
    borderwidth=0,
    compound=tkinter.TOP
    )
milchButton4 = tkinter.Button(
    text="core1",
    font=("Arial",14),
    image=photo,
    command=core1,
    highlightthickness=0,
    borderwidth=0,
    compound=tkinter.TOP
    )
milchButton5 = tkinter.Button(
    text="core2",
    font=("Arial",14),
    image=photo,
    command=core2,
    highlightthickness=0,
    borderwidth=0,
    compound=tkinter.TOP
    )
milchButton6 = tkinter.Button(
    text="rt030bd",
    font=("Arial",14),
    image=photo,
    command=rt030bd,
    highlightthickness=0,
    borderwidth=0,
    compound=tkinter.TOP
    )
milchButton7 = tkinter.Button(
    text="rt030ac",
    font=("Arial",14),
    image=photo,
    command=rt030ac,
    highlightthickness=0,
    borderwidth=0,
    compound=tkinter.TOP
    )
    
milchButton.place(relx=0.01,rely=0.37,anchor=tkinter.NW)
milchButton2.place(relx=0.01,rely=0.63,anchor=tkinter.NW)
milchButton3.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.1,anchor=tkinter.NW)
milchButton4.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.47,anchor=tkinter.NW)
milchButton5.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.47,anchor=tkinter.NW)
milchButton6.place(relx=0.8,rely=0.63,anchor=tkinter.NW)
milchButton7.place(relx=0.8,rely=0.37,anchor=tkinter.NW)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Without external libraries the solution is much much harder, using only `ctypes.windll`, you have to get the handle to the window openned by putty, then post a message to it to maximize it, ...without using even psutils you have a lot of coding to do ... Basically get the pid of the program then more commands to get the handles, etc, about a few pages worth of win32 dll calls that are doing what a few Libraries out there are ment to do.

Comment: You can install libraries on a company's laptop, you only need to use a venv so it won't clash with the system's interpreter libraries, and you won't need admin privileges for it.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to install PyGetWindow as .whl and complete the program using it.

```
import pygetwindow
def checkWindow(router):
    WindowList = pygetwindow.getAllTitles()
    for Window in WindowList:
        if str(Window) == '{} - PuTTY'.format(router):
            putty = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('{} - PuTTY'.format(router))[0]
            putty.activate()
            putty.restore()
            return 0
    os.system("start C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\putty.exe -load {}".format(router))
```

Comment: *"Install a library"* is not a solution to a problem statement that says: *"I cannot install libraries"*. This may solve your immediate issue, but it doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: I couldnt install libraries directly from the Internet, as such traffic is blocked by the company. Installing them by downloading the .whl file first solved this issue.

Comment: Exactly, it solved *your* issue, but doesn't otherwise provide an answer to the question. Probably a good idea to take the [tour].